# in Angular2 how to know when ANY form input field lost focus

Tags: angular

In Angular2 how to know when ANY input field has lost focus..!
If I use observables on the form:

```ts
form.valueChange.subscribe...
```

wont work since I really want to know when a field lost it's blur (focus) so I can update my store (if I update the store before losing focus, my cursor on a text input gets moved to the end, since the data gets swapped which is weird looking)

of course I can also add `(change)=""` on each input, but I have a lot of'em...

I was thinking something of the sorts of:

```ts
this.form.valueChanges.debounceTime(1000).subscribe((changes:any) => {
  if (this.form.dirty){
    this.appStore.dispatch(this.resellerAction.updateResellerInfo(changes))
  }
});
```

but the problem is that the dirty remains dirty, so it stuck in an everlasting loop of change detections...

tx

Sean

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `blur` event doesn't bubble, therefore we need to listen on every input element directly. Angular provides a nice solution for this situation.

A directive that applies to all input elements inside your template.

This directive uses a host-listener to listen for the `blur` events on all elements where the selector applies and forwards a bubbling `input-blur` event:

```ts
@Directive({
  selector: 'input,select',
  host: {'(blur)': 'onBlur($event)'}
})
class BlurForwarder {
  constructor(private elRef:ElementRef, private renderer:Renderer) {}

  onBlur($event) {
    this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.elRef.nativeElement, 
        'dispatchEvent', 
        [new CustomEvent('input-blur', { bubbles: true })]);
    // or just 
    // el.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('input-blur', { bubbles: true }));
    // if you don't care about webworker compatibility
  }
}
```

By adding the `BlurForwarder` directive to `directives: [...]` it will be applied to all elements in its template that match the selector.
The host-listener listens for bubbling `input-blur` events and calls our event handler:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  directives: [BlurForwarder],
  host: {'(input-blur)':'onInputBlur($event)'},
  template: `
<form>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="xxx">
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="yyy">
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="zzz">
</form>`
}) {
  onInputBlur(event) {
    doSomething();
  }
}
```

Comment: SWEEEEET.... just tested and it worked GREAT!!!  u d man Gunter!!!! I was able to remove all my (change)="onChange($event)" from the form

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer, do you have an alternative solution for rc6? I believe directives are deprecated in that version. Thanks!

Comment: just move `directives` to `declarations in `@NgModule(...)`

Comment: this is exactly what I've been looking for

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I've been reading up on HostBinding / HostListener and it seems like the style guide recommends we utilize these over the "host" property on the component decorator.  Is this possible, and if so, could you provide an example? All the examples seem to only show setting these attributes on the directive itself.  Thanks!

Comment: `@HostListener` is just different syntax for the same thing

Comment: Thank you, you've saved my day :)

Comment: Glad to hear that worked for you. The stackblitz reproduction was very helpful.

Comment: _The answer about `focusout` is superior and should be used instead._ focusout is supported by all browsers including IE going back to IE 8. This spins up a component and listeners for every single input/select, and won't work for any other custom controls you have in the future. You could certainly retrofit the code above to use it, but focusout is what you should be using, its much, much, much more efficient.

Answer (score 13):

Why not use [focusout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focusout) it bubbles by default in the DOM

Here's a simple directive that catches focusout and checks if input value is blank, then sets value to zero:

```ts
@Directive({
  selector: '[blankToZero]'
})
export class BlankToZeroDirective {
  constructor(private elementHost: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('focusout')
  ensureInput(): void {
    if (Util.isNullOrEmpty(this.elementHost.nativeElement.value)) {
      this.elementHost.nativeElement.value = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Best solution, simple and native

Comment: why not elaborate on your answer a little bit more, maybe add an example?

Comment: This is the best solution, and I would have posted it myself if it weren't already here. The accepted answer spins up an entire component and listeners for every single form field in the DOM whereby focusout could be used at the root of the form, one and done.
_I repeat, this is a superior answer!!_

Comment: No there could be situations where you want to have this functionality selectively and hence accepted answer is better. e.g. in our case we want to do analytics call on certain elements only when user burs out with single focusout on form its too generic and doesnt help to apply the solution selectively.

Comment: In year 2023 this does not work any longer for Angular 15