# how to get input field name through event object in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, angular

I am not sure whether its logical to get.
Here is the html code for my input box.

```
<input type="text" id="name" #name="ngForm" [ngFormControl]="userProfileForm.controls['name']"  
             [(ngModel)]="loggedUserInfo.name" (change)="firechange($event,'name')"
             />
```

and here is my firechange function

```
 firechange($event, field){
      if(this.userProfileForm.controls[field].valid){
       this._userService.updateUserProfile(this.loggedUserInfo);
       this._userService.loadUserData(); 
      }
 }
```

I want to pass only the event in the firechange function and inside the fire change function I want to get the input field name from the event so that I can understand that which input field in my form triggered the event. Expected code will be something like that

```
[ngFormControl]="userProfileForm.controls['name']"  
                 [(ngModel)]="loggedUserInfo.name" (change)="firechange($event)"
                 />

firechange($event){
          if(this.userProfileForm.controls[$event.fieldname].valid){
           this._userService.updateUserProfile(this.loggedUserInfo);
           this._userService.loadUserData(); 
          }
 }
```

My ideal requirement is, in a form there are number of form fields, I don't even want to write firechange function in each individual form field. Is there any generic way to call the event on each input field value change for a particular form without writing it on each input field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `id` is the same as the name you are passing you can get the name like

```
firechange(event){
  if(this.userProfileForm.controls[$event.target.id].valid){
}
```

Comment: can you please provide a handy solution for my last paragraph?

Comment: Not sure what you're actually trying to accomplish. Maybe `this.userProfileForm.valueChanges.subscribe(...`) is what you are looking for. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/34616143/217408

Answer (score 3):

To get the actual name of the element you can do the following:

```
firechange(event){
     var name = event.target.attributes.getNamedItem('ng-reflect-name').value;
     console.log('name')
}
```

Comment: That's handy -- proprietary, but handy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get hold of the element from within your fire change function you may want to try something like:

```
firechange(event){
          let theElement = event.target;
          // now theElement holds the html element which you can query for name, value and so on
 }
```

If you in addition you want to instruct your component to apply the firechange() logic on all of your input fields with one single instruction in your component (and not having to specify this on every single input field) than I suggest you to look at [in Angular2 how to know when ANY form input field lost focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36342890/in-angular2-how-to-know-when-any-form-input-field-lost-focus).

I hope this helps

Comment: i tried with this but it prints the this ` <input id="name" class="ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty" type="text" _ngcontent-kxr-3="">` that is not my purpose, i want to have the id or ngControl name of the input field.

Answer (score 0):

#### If `id` is not the same or it can change, here's more leverage...

You may want to reflect the `[name]` *property* the the element's *attribute*:

```
... #input [name]="item.name" [attr.name]="item.name" (change)="fn(input)" ...
```

Then,

```
...
fn(input) {
    log(input.name);  // now it returns the name
}
...
```

[See more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42878385/angular2-binding-of-name-attribute-in-input-elements-with-ngfor)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" (change)="firechange($event.target.value)">
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Angular 10

```
$event.source.name
```

Comment: I had to use `event.source.ngControl.name`