# Angular2 binding of "name" attribute in <input> elements with *ngFor

Tags: angular, input, angular-material2, ngfor

I am experimenting with Angular2 and Angular Material. I used `*ngFor` to let Angular generate the `<input>` elements for me. However, in the resulting webpage, the generated element does not have `name` attribute.

This is part of the code in `order-form.component.html`, which asks the user to input the number of different kinds of fruits:

```ts
<md-list-item>
  <md-icon md-list-icon>shopping_cart</md-icon>
  <md-input-container *ngFor="let fruit of fruits" class="fruit-input">
    <input mdInput [(ngModel)]="order[fruit]" [placeholder]="capitalize(fruit)" 
           [id]="fruit" name="{{fruit}}" required value="0" #fruitInput 
           (input)="onInput(fruitInput)">
  </md-input-container>
</md-list-item>
```

This is the corresponding `order-form.component.ts`:

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Order } from "app/order";
import { PAYMENTS } from "app/payments";
import { OrderService } from "app/order.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-order-form',
  templateUrl: './order-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./order-form.component.css']
})
export class OrderFormComponent implements OnInit {

  order = new Order();

  payments = PAYMENTS;

  fruits: string[] = [
    'apples',
    'oranges',
    'bananas'
  ];

  constructor(public service: OrderService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  get totalCost() {
    return this.service.getTotalCost(this.order);
  }

  onFocus(element: HTMLElement) {
    element.blur();
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log('onSubmit');
  }

  onInput(element: HTMLInputElement) {
    console.log(element);
    if (!this.service.isValidIntString(element.value)) {
      window.alert(`Please input a correct number for ${element.name}`);
      element.value = '0';
    }
  }

  capitalize(str: string): string {
    return this.service.capitalize(str);
  }

  get debug() {
    return JSON.stringify(this.order, null, 2);
  }
}
```

In the Chrome browser, when I right click the 'apples' `<input>`, the `name` attribute of the element is empty, but the `ng-reflect-name` is set to `apples` correctly? How to resolve this problem?
[No `name` attribute here, but `ng-reflect-name` is `apples`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sapY7.png)

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: @Aravind From the console below, there are no errors.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**final answer**

Use (`[name]="fruit"` or `name="{{fruit}}"`) and (`[attr.name]="fruit"` or `attr.name="{{fruit}}"`) together will work.

**update**

If you want to use the string `'fruit'` as value for the `name` attribute, use

```ts
name="fruit"
```

or

```ts
name="{{'fruit'}}"
```

or

```ts
[name]="'fruit'"
```

otherwise you bind the value of the components field `fruit` (which your component doesn't seem to have)

**original**

Angular does property binding by default. If you want attribute binding you need to make that explicit

```ts
 attr.name="{{fruit}}" (for strings only)
```

or

```ts
 [name]="fruit"
```

See also

- [Angular 2 data attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34542619/angular-2-data-attributes/34542844#34542844)
- [How to add conditional attribute in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745734/how-to-add-conditional-attribute-in-angular-2/36745752#36745752)
- [What is the difference between attribute and property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258469/what-is-the-difference-between-attribute-and-property)

Comment: When i use `attr.name="{{fruit}}"` the browser will give me error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions. When I use `[name]="fruit"` the result is not change at all.

Comment: Then the problem is something else. So you don't actually care about the `name` attribute being added to the `<input>`, you just want the `ngModel` to work?

Comment: I think you actually want `name="fruit"`

Comment: `ngModel` is working. No issue. When I key in any thing the bottom json string will change accordingly. What I do want is to add the `name` attribute into the `input` element. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, what I want is for 'apples', the `name` is `apples`, for `oranges`, the name is `oranges`,  etc. If I change `name="fruit"`, the `name` attribute is still not shown.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `fruit` in  `*ngFor`. Still, in this case my original answer is to get the attribute `name` added to the DOM. If `ngModel` doesn't work this way you might need both `attr.name="{{fruit}}" name="{{fruit}}"` (but I would find this weird)

Comment: Thank you! It works when I put both `name={{fruit}}` and `attr.name={{fruit}}`. But why?

Comment: To add the attribute you need `attr.name={{fruit}}`. `ngModel` somehow doesn't seem to take the attribute and depends on a property binding. Sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: But the `fruit` is not from `ngModel`. It's just the variable used in `*ngFor`, i.e., in the `<md-input-container>` I have `*ngFor="let fruit of fruits"`. I also think it's kind of a bug. Anyways, could you change your answer to using both so that I can set it as the correct answer?

Comment: I don't think that is a bug. If we use template expression like `name={{fruit}}` then it is only property binding. If we use one time binding like `name="constantString"` then it will set attribute and also provide Input binding to directive. Using `attr.name` is right way i think `[attr.name]="fruit"` should also work

Comment: @yurzui If I only use `attr.name` Angular will just complain an error to me. I have to use both.

Comment: Yes, you have to use both because ngModel requires `@Input() name`

Comment: `attr.name="{{...}}"` is passed to `@Input() name` as well. It has to be something else.

Comment: @yurzui Can you be more specific on `@Input() name`? Like how do I change my component so that I can use `[attr.name]="fruit"` only?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/Mc00Msri3fxwTskGeSxx?p=preview `attr.name="{{..}}"` is not passed to `@Input name`

Comment: Is it because of the Angular2 material library? Because when I change your code to simply using `name="{{fruit}}"`, the `name` attribute is there. When I try to create a new `<input>` at the bottom using the same `*ngFor` and same `[name]="fruit"` the `name` attribute is correctly shown.

Comment: I just found that if I remove `[(ngModel)]` it will work with single `[name]="fruit"`. But once I add back `[(ngModel)]` the `name` is gone.

Comment: @saghar.fadaei is `fruit` the name of a variable or the string literal you want to use? In the later case you should use `name="fruit"`

Comment: For `[attr.name]="value"` and `[name]="value"`, what is the difference?

Comment: The later will cause an exception if the HTML  element does not have a property with this name and also not hosts an Angular component or directive that does not have an `@Input() name;` . See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/what-is-the-difference-between-properties-and-attributes-in-html