# How to set variable attribute as #variable="ngModel" in form input?

Tags: angular

I am updating my project's angular version from `v2.0.0-beta.6` to `v4.1.1`.

Normally, I update from

```
<input type="text" ngControl="name" .../>
```

to

```
<input type="text" #name="ngModel" .../>
```

It works well in my project until I met this:

```
<input type="text" required ngControl="{{[param.key]}}"  [(ngModel)]="params[param.key]" ... />
```

How can I set the attribute name variable? 
Thanks!

Comment: I think `<input type="text" #name="ngModel" .../>` should be `<input type="text" name="name" .../>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 binding of "name" attribute in <input> elements with \*ngFor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42878385/angular2-binding-of-name-attribute-in-input-elements-with-ngfor)

Comment: Thanks. It works well when I add `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"` in my input. Sometimes I just can't get the deep difference between `name` attribute and `[ngModelOptions]` when I used `[(ngModel)]` in my input.