# Angular 2.0 are inputs value or event based?

Tags: angular

Imagine I would have a component which should receive events, a "player" for instance. The user will likely want to trigger an event to the player, such as "play" or "pause".  In my understanding, the `@inputs` are basically a value we send to the component (and not an event). What is the good practice to trigger those events to the component ?

Considering a player example:
- The player has no UI, it's only a tag able to load a source file.
- We need to find a convenient way to drive this player firing events such as "start", "stop", "pause"…

I thought about passing an eventEmitter in parameter such as `<player [controls]=controls src="somefile.mp3"/>` where the `control` would be the EventEmitter. Then, the component's controller would internally observe this emitter's events and act accordingly (play, stop, pause…).

Any other solution / convention to achieve this ?

More ideas:

- Create custom specific event on the player's dom element then [trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript) the event
- Find a way to get the component's controller within the code and directly call public functions such as play(), pause()…. but then it might be an antipatern with webworkers.

Comment: How are player and controls related? What is `controls`? With a more concrete example it would be easier to make suggestions.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I edited the question to clarify

Comment: I updated my answer. Using `@ViewChild()` to get a reference to the player and calling methods on it works fine with WebWorkers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a component to respond to received events you can use `@HostListener()`

```ts
@Component({
  ...
})
class SomePlayer {
  @HostListener('play', ['$event'])
  onPlay(event) {
    ...
  }
}
```

If you use the `Renderer` like shown in [in Angular2 how to know when ANY form input field lost focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36342890/in-angular2-how-to-know-when-any-form-input-field-lost-focus/36348311#36348311) to dispatch an event it will work fine with WebWorkers.

You can also use

```ts
@HostListener('window:play', ['$event'])
```

to listen to these events globally.

I'm not sure this is the best solution for your situation.
This only listens to events that are fired inside of `SomePlayer`. Only DOM events are bubbling, while events emitted from `EventEmitter` are not.

One way would be to use a template variable to be able to reference the player directly from the control and call methods on the `MyPlayer` component directly.

```ts
<player-control (play)="player.play()" (stop)="player.stop()"></player-control>
<my-player #player><my-player>
```

You can also use

```ts
@ViewChild(MyPlayer) player:MyPlayer;

buttonClickHandler() {
  this.player.play();
}
```

from the component class that has `<my-player>` in its template.