# Performing Click on an ElementRef object in Angular 4

Tags: html, angular, single-page-application

I want to perform a click on an element of html page from its component class.

I have obtain the reference of the element in component class like this

```
@ViewChild('secondForm') input: ElementRef;
```

Now I want to perform a click on this input from a function lets say clickOnInput like this

```
public clickOnInput(){
 this.input.click() // I cannot find this function,
}
```

Is there any way or any other method to click on html elements from Angular's component class?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639486/angular2-manually-firing-click-event-on-particular-element

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40103772/how-to-trigger-click-on-an-html-file-element-from-a-component-angular-2