# Is it possible to set variable javascript variables outside from angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, constructor

I am new to angular2 and used a component which is from other library and I want to pass a data from angular2 . My problem is that , I can't set the variable if its not from angular2 to that third party component.

Can anyone enlighten me if its possible?

Ex.

```
//hmtl outside angular2
somepage.html
 var somevar; //variable on somepage.html

//component from angular2
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit{


constructor{
 //id like to assign a value to somevar from inside this component
 somevar = "blah blah";
}


}
```

Regards,
Erwin

Comment: Not very clear.

Comment: Could you please add some code that demonstrates what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: i have added some example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hmtl outside angular2**

```
window['SomeVarUpdated'] = function (newValue) {
  // do something
};
```

**component from angular2**

```
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor() {
    window['SomeVarUpdated']("blah blah");
  }
}
```

Comment: this seems to be working! I'll take it from here. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can assign to `window` and then also access it from everywhere else this way:

```
constructor{
  //id like to assign a value to somevar from inside this component
  window.somevar = "blah blah";
}
```

Comment: having (index):42 Uncaught ReferenceError: somevar is not defined when i do that

Comment: when i read it . I tried to alert it from somepage.html . Was expecting that variable will have a value.

Comment: Then you obviously read it before the constructor that writes it is executed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I agree it was loaded first before the constructor.

Comment: You can dispatch a custom event to notify the external JS script that the value is available like shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36342890/in-angular2-how-to-know-when-any-form-input-field-lost-focus/36348311#36348311