# Emit and broadcast events throughout application in Angular

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-services, eventemitter, behaviorsubject

Is there a way to emit event in angular2 that can be listened to in entire application? Like we had in AngularJS using `$rootScope.broadcast` and `emit`. Can this same thing be achieved in angular2? I read about `@Output()` and `EventEmitter()` and implemented it but it restricts only the parent to listen to the event emmitted by child.

I read about `BehaviorSubject` being one of the ways to do this. Is that the right approach? Any other solution for this?

Comment: Using observables seems to be a good option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-or-observable-in-angular2/35568924#35568924

Comment: You can add an observable to your parent that get's set when the child emits.  You can then subscribe to that observable anywhere you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Angular2 there is no global scope. There are only components and services.

With services you can define their scope by the place you provide them. If you provide one in `@NgModule({providers: ...})` (or in an imported module) it becomes globally avialable. If you provide it at a component, it is only available to this component and its children.

You can also dispatch a bubbling DOM event like shown in [in Angular2 how to know when ANY form input field lost focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36342890/in-angular2-how-to-know-when-any-form-input-field-lost-focus/36348311#36348311)

Events emitted with `@Output() someOutput:EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();` don't bubble.

Comment: `BehaviorSubject` is an easy way. Hardcore reactivionists think that `Subject` should be avoided. http://davesexton.com/blog/post/To-Use-Subject-Or-Not-To-Use-Subject.aspx, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396449/why-are-subjects-not-recommended-in-net-reactive-extensions So this is an opinionated question. If you are new to rxjs I'd suggest you use it until you are more comfortable with reactive programming and you are able to decide for yourself.

Comment: Thanks Gunter!! I shall do it. Just wanted to confirm for my knowledge Is services the best way to do it?

Comment: Services is **the** way to do it in Angular2.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer - Thanks for that explanation. However, did you mean to post that gitlab link to dart-lang? I think you had something unexpected on your clipboard when you wrote the article.

Comment: @jessewolfe Thanks. I removed it. Can't remember what I meant to post instead :D